# Is it allowed to use non-English language in comment/answer?

Tags: discussion, languages, english

Let's say, I found someone who is asking a question is from the same country with me, is it allowed to use my own speaking language to help her/him?

Comment: You shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Lucifer yes, I understand.

Comment: It would be embarrassing if the person was lying about where they were from and didn't actually understand the language you'd be writing. Besides, why would you answer a question that was asked in English, in something other than English? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Good certain it does. Who sayt if I talks well the english? My answer would be alloud be very confusing on english. [for illutration purposes]

Answer (score 23):

By doing that, you would be limiting your answer's audience to users who speak your native language.

Other users will not benefit from your answer and will be unable to upvote it, even if it is very good, since they cannot understand it.

This is a lose-lose situation. Don't do that.

Comment: do you mean 'nobody disallow it but just dont' ??

Comment: Our policy [disallows it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/), except in some very specific cases (mostly the "X language and usage" sites). Comments are more of a gray area, if you ask me, since their content is less essential, so you might get away with posting comments in your native language. They will almost always confuse the other users, though.

Comment: Comments are secondary to answers and also constitute as content. Comments shouldn't be in anything others than English as well. Have you ever been to an English forum, looked at a thread you found interesting then discovered 80% of the comments are in a language you can't understand? How annoying is that? We want to avoid that here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Non-english comments will most likely be flagged and subsequently removed.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that. English language required.

If you want to discuss with him, you can use chat. you can do chat with him.

Comment: Not sure about "English language required", but it's quite normal to see a non-English post being obliterated in minutes, so I'd assume it is at least *de facto*. +1 for the suggestion to use chat room.

Answer (score 4):

While using local language, One of the drawback I can see is the other users who doesn't understand the non-english/local language will surely flag those comments/answer which will increase moderator's work to review those posts. The result of such review will 100% be deleting those posts.

So the best would be to use English language.